# how to perform a conditional query on rtl languages in SQl

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to perform conditional query on a table that holds right to left language. 
I have used stored procedure to query database from my win form. 
code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE filerPROC
@Person nchar(50),
@email nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN 
    select lastname,DOB from Employee where name = @Person
END
```

when i get the result. it is all ??? instead of person name. how to configure table to work right? i have alreadt tried using N keword, but it gives me syntax error.

```
insert into Employee (N'rtl lang'......)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually if your database default collation is not set to your purpose language this problem may happen. 
simply write the following code based on your selected language :

```
ALTER database 'database name' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

after the word 'collate' you can replace any language you want. see here :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your application code is not passing the value to @Person in unicode. I see this a lot.  You may need to code it as UTF-8.